# Basic tools for digital filter design?

Tags: filter-design, digital-filters

- What tools to use for practicing elementary filter design?
- Is MATLAB all there is?
- Do I need some specific toolboxes?
- What functions do I need?

I'm starting from the ground up in digital filter design and I thought that I need to decide on a program that lets me experiment with different filter designs (not pre-built functions, but rather self-written). Make plots and perhaps `.wav` outputs and such.

I'm looking for something higher level than C++, because I think the "design language" should allow for more rapid prototyping than the "implementation language".

The tools should facilitate the evaluation of filter designs.

Comment: basic matlab + signal processing toolbox and dsp knowledge is enough to design and implement most practical filters, but you will seriously take advantage of a filter design toolbox...

Comment: Also, filter design is **extremely** application-specific. I'd go as far as to say it's easy to build a filter that does a single job, but it's often hard to know which class of filters you need to use.

Comment: Ie. **what is your application, what kind of filters are you looking for?**

Comment: And usually, you don't *need* Matlab. That is just really handy for those used to it, and has immensely comprehensive toolboxes. If you just need to design a few low, high or bandpass linear or minimal phase filters, I'd go for scipy or octave.

Comment: Also if you are a competent programmer in **C** or C++ and say in Windows or Linux **API** programming. Then you need nothing else to design and implement digital filters, other than a **cookbook** and **numerical libraries** together with a **free compiler**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots and lots of software that can aid you in designing digital filters. MATLAB is probably the most used software, at least in the university sector. The  [DSP toolbox](http://au.mathworks.com/products/dsp-system/features.html#single-rate-and-multirate-fir-and-iir-filter-design%2C-and-adaptive-filters) and the [signal processing toolbox](http://au.mathworks.com/products/signal/features.html#digital-and-analog-filters) probably cover all of the well-known methods for digital filter design, as already mentioned.

Alternatives to MATLAB (that are free) include: [Julia](http://julialang.org), [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org), and [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org) (Python with libraries for technical computing). There are a lot of others, but these are the ones that I know have high quality libraries/methods for filter design.

For Julia, you can use the [Filters.jl](http://dspjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html) package, for Octave the [signal package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/overview.html), for Scilab the [Signal Processing toolbox](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/section_dbbac6be408104de3049eddefaf6b9c9.html), and for SciPy you have [scipy.signal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html).

A lot of filter design is done using optimization, and if you want to customize the cost-function or make other tweaks to e.g. the least-squares method or the Parks-McClellan method, you could have a look at a high-level optimization library such as [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) (works with MATLAB and Julia ++), or [JuMP](http://www.juliaopt.org) for Julia.

These are just the tools that I have a fair bit of familiarity with...

Answer (score 0):

There are also some interesting on-line tools that can be used to design the filter and obtain the filter coefficients. These can be copy-pasted to the code and then be used to implement the desired transfer function.

Check:

- TFilter. http://t-filter.engineerjs.com/
- FIIR. https://fiiir.com/

Both have lots of options to explore.